# Can a string be converted into a valid condition to use in an *ngIf to filter Data?

Tags: angular

I want to know if it is possible to put in a variable a condition made in a string, which will then be read as a real condition in an * ngIf

```
In .ts:
this.aData=
[
  { "color":blue,"max":0; min:1, name:"joe","city":"neardenlans"...},
  { "color":red,"max":50; min:5, name:"joe","city":"manila"...},
  { "color":pink,"max":100; min:25, name:"joe","city":"neardenlans"...},
  { "color":gray,"max":0; min:63, name:"joe","city":"new york"...},
  .
  .
  .
]
.
.

//At this point I have done many operations, loops and calculations to establish the conditions to filter the data I need.
this.condition="color=='pink' and 'max'== 2 && name=='joe' and ....."

In HTML:
<div *ngFor="let item of aData"
 <span *ngIf="condition">
  //show data that fullfill the conditions
 </span>
</div>
```

to this:

Strictly I need to follow this way, in my real project I have enough conditions that **depend on certain behaviors**, so for me it is somewhat difficult to put everything in the HTML template. after several operations and `loops` I can know what comparisons I should make. The result is to `filter the data` that meet these conditions.
I appreciate the help..
Maybe it seems crazy or something weird, but I need to follow this way. I appreciate the understanding

Thank you

Comment: Given your case.. Why not skip the *ngIf and handle the filtering of data within your component itself?  Your component.html will look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

**TS**

```
aData = [
    { "color":"blue","max":0, min:1, name:"joe","city":"neardenlans"},
    { "color":"red","max":50, min:5, name:"joe","city":"manila"},
    { "color":"pink","max":100, min:25, name:"joe","city":"neardenlans"},
    { "color":"gray","max":0, min:63, name:"joe","city":"new york"}
] 

condition(item) {
    if(item.color == 'pink' && item.max == 100 && item.name == 'joe') {
      return item;
    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aData">
 <span *ngIf="condition(item)">
  Name: {{item.name}}
  Color: {{item.color}}
  Max: {{item.max}}
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but you did not understand my question. that's what I want to avoid (*ngIf="item.color == 'pink' && item.max == 100 && item.name == 'joe'"). I want that in a string from the .ts I can put it in the *ngIf="condition"

Comment: I don't think it can be achieve by just adding **condition** string. If you want you move string in ts you have use method in ngif and send item as a parameter. Thanks

Comment: I just update the above code with condition method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you must, and you only want to have ANDed clauses, and your clauses are simple equality checks (as your question formulation suggests)... then make your `*ngIf="condition(item, conditions)"`

Here `conditions` would be a class member variable which is an array of objects of the form `{key: string, value: any}` which you would build that array *instead of* your string expression, and `condition` would be a function you define in your typescript something like this:

```
condition(item, conditions) {
  if(!item) return false;
  if(!Array.isArray(conditions) || (conditions.length === 0)) return true;
  for(let i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++) {
    if(item[conditions[i].key] !== conditions[i].value) {
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```